# vb.net im getting error

Tags: vb.net

```
 Public Function Cricket() As List(Of String)
    Dim list2 As New List(Of String)() With { _
        "Bat", _
        "ball", _
        "Cricket", _
        "baseball", _
        "MLB", _
        "Derbyshire", _
        "Durham", _
        "Essex", _
        "Glamorgan", _
        "Gloucestershire", _
        "Hampshire", _      

    }
        'string str;
        Return list2
    End Function
```

the error is  Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Dim list2 As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) _
        (New String() {"Bat", "ball", "Cricket"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `From` instead of `With`.

```
Dim list2 As New List(Of String)() From { _
    "Bat", _
    "ball", _
    ...
}
```

`With` is used for object initializers; `From` is used for collection initializers.